# How to move/copy files during ember build

Tags: ember-cli, broccolijs

I wanted to moved some files between two folders in an ember app when build is run but I am having no success.

```
//ember-cli-build.js
module.exports = function (defaults) {

    var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
        hinting: false,
        minifyCSS: {
            enabled: true
        },
        bless: {
            enabled: true
        }
    });

    var moveFile = new Funnel('./app/locales', {
        srcDir: 'en',
        files: ['test.js'],
        destDir: 'en_US',
        allowEmpty: true
    });


    return new MergeTrees([moveFile, app.toTree()]);
};
```

When I do the build, I get no errors but the file is also not getting moved.

UPDATE: I am trying to move the file before ember-cli puts compiles the files and puts it in the dist folder

Comment: I'm just learning broccoli, but it seems like your code will take `./app/locales/en/test.js` as it's input, and output that file to `<output-dir>/en_US/test.js`,  Is that right?

Comment: Yes, it should try to put the file in app/locales/en_US/ folder

Answer (score 0):

You can use `broccoli-static-compiler` https://github.com/joliss/broccoli-static-compiler

In brocfile.js ( ember-cli-build.js )

```
// at top of file
var pickFiles = require('broccoli-static-compiler');
var mergeTrees = require('broccoli-merge-trees');

// inside exporting function

  const bootstrapMap = pickFiles('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/',
    {
      srcDir: '/',
      files: ['bootstrap.css.map'],
      destDir: '/assets'
    });
  // and so on, as many times as you need
  const zeroClipboard = pickFiles('bower_components/zeroclipboard/dist/',
    {
      srcDir: '/',
      files: ['ZeroClipboard.swf'],
      destDir: '/assets'
    });

// at the end
  return mergeTrees([
    app.toTree(),
    bootstrapMap,
    zeroClipboard,
    // ...
  ], { overwrite: true });
```

Comment: Vasiliy, thanks for the response but it seems like funnel is doing the same thing as broccoli-static-compiler, even in their git repo they recommend using Funnel instead which I am using.

Answer (score 0):

With 'broccoli build', your app is build into a destination folder, so broccoli is the wrong tool to move files in an existing folder structure.  Here I'm assuming it's run with something like 'broccoli build dist' on the command line which will create a new folder 'dist' with the results of the build, and error out if the directory already exists.

So let's say your project directory looks like this:

```
.
|--brocfile.js
|--app/
  |--locales/        <----- funnel root
     |--en/          <----- srcDir
        |--test.js   <----- file
```

When you funnel from `./app/locales`, your srcDir and files` are relative to that as a root.  The output tree is then put into the 'destDir' under the build output directory.  What that will do is this:

```
.
|--brocfile.js
|--app/              <----- not changed
|--dist/             <----- build output directory
   |--en_US          <----- destDir
      |--test.js     <----- file
```

I think you want your `destDir` to be `locales/en_US` or `app/locales/en_US`.